# QFileDialog filter unknown file types only

Tags: python, filter, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

```
QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Choose File', self.filelocation, filter="?" (*)")
```

When I try to select files with QFileDialog, it shows me all the files - but I want to filter only unknown file-types, as seen in below picture. Is it possible? Or how can I disable .txt files?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown"? That word is generally used for *any* file that has no *known* extension (including no extension).

Comment: Yes, it has no extension.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you must use a [proxy model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setProxyModel) for this, because the [name-filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setNameFilters) use [wildcard matching](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#wildcard-matching) (which doesn't support negated patterns like `!(*.*)`), and the [mime-filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setMimeTypeFilters) don't seem to recognise any kind of "unknown" file-type.

Below is a working solution that uses a [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). The logic in `filterAcceptsRow` just allows through all directories and any files with no dots, but you can easily adjust it as you see fit. (To get more details about a file, you could use e.g. `info = model.fileInfo(index)` to obtain a [QFileInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html) object).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        model = self.sourceModel()
        index = model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        return model.isDir(index) or '.' not in model.fileName(index)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        self.sourceModel().sort(column, order)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])

dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
dialog.setWindowTitle('Choose Files')
dialog.setProxyModel(ProxyModel())
dialog.exec()
```

A further refinement might be to [check the mime-type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html), since the extension alone may be unreliable. The unknown file-type should be equivalent to the default mime-type (i.e. *application/octet-stream*), so a basic implementation would be:

```
class ProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    mimetypes = QtCore.QMimeDatabase()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        model = self.sourceModel()
        index = model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        return model.isDir(index) or (
            '.' not in model.fileName(index) and
            self.mimetypes.mimeTypeForFile(
                model.fileInfo(index)).isDefault())

    def sort(self, column, order):
        self.sourceModel().sort(column, order)
```